# Computability problem/exercice -- can't solve

Tags: recursion, computability

I'm really blocked in the first part of the below exercise and can't solve it. It would be great if you could help!

Show that there exists a partial recursive function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that :
$$W_i \neq \emptyset \implies g(i) \in W_i$$
Moreover, show that there exists a total recursive function $\gamma$ such that :
$$ W_{\gamma(i)}\subset W_i \text{ and } (W_i \neq \emptyset \implies card(W_{\gamma(i)}) = 1) $$
Then, show that given a partial recursive function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ then there exists a total function $a$ such that :
$$ f(x) \downarrow \implies W_{a(x)} = \bigcup_{i \leq f(x)} W_{\gamma(i)}$$

N.B. $f(x) \downarrow$ translates to $f$ is defined on $x$, and $W_i$ is the definitional domain of the universal function $\phi_i$.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: You basically have to use the definition of recursively enumerable set. You may think in terms of Turing machines if it helps. Where are you stuck at? Can you get the first one to work?

Comment: Yes, I finally got the first one, i.e. $f(i) = \mu y. \phi(i, y) \downarrow$, (but I have some trouble with this definition as it does not seem intuitively correct ). For the second one, I think we have to assume the axiom of choice and work toward this direction. something like $g(i, n) = f(i)$ if $\phi_i(n) \downarrow$ and $\uparrow$ otherwise. Then, $\phi(e, i, n) = g(i, n)$ and by snm $\phi(e, i, n) = \phi(s_1^1(e, i), n) = \phi(\gamma(i), n)$. Then we have the second claim as an extension of the first. The third would probably use the fixed point lemma.